# Symbolic constants in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am playing around with homogeneous transformations in MATLAB.
I got a Transformation which looks like this

```
>> T01

T01 =

[ cos(phi1), -sin(phi1), 0, 0]
[ sin(phi1),  cos(phi1), 0, 0]
[         0,          0, 1, 0]
[         0,          0, 0, 1]
```

A simple rotation around the z axis. I used `phi1=sym('phi1')`. Now if i calculate the inverse `T01 * inv(T01)` MATLAB is not displaying the Identity matrix but rather a matrix with huge expressions. If i use any explicit values for `phi1`, it works. How can i make MATLAB cancel out symbolic values?

Thanks

EDIT: Interestingly, for some operations it does cancel out symbolic constants:

```
>> (phi1*phi2)/phi1

ans =

phi2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `simplify`

```
>> simplify(T01*inv(T01))


ans =

[ 1, 0, 0, 0]
[ 0, 1, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 1, 0]
[ 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Probably for performance reasons, only very simple simplification rules are applied automatically in each step.